# Custom PHP not being picked up

Tags: php

I've been pulling my hair out trying to get this working. There is a file in core that throws up errors using the SagePay extension from Circle. I can edit the core .php file and fix the problem. Obviously each time I update it is overwritten. So I have created the same directory structure under civicrm_custom_php and added the edited file. Directory paths are correct, but the file in custom isn't being picked up. Any hints or tips really appreciated on getting this working. I am running CiviCRM 5.6.0 on Drupal 7.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The SagePay extension from Circle is outdated and is not supported for 5.x version. Mattwire has integrated sagepay payment processor in Eileen's [CiviCRM OmniPay Multiprocessor](https://civicrm.org/extensions/omnipay-multiprocessor-extension) extension. The simplest, easy and recommended solution would be to install the omnipay extension from Matt's git [repository](https://github.com/mattwire/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor/archive/sagepay.zip)(sagepay branch). Move old payment processor from all Contribution and event pages to new sagepay payment processor either by running sql or updating manually.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Are there any special considerations / warnings for dealing with old contributions (especially recurring ones) which would relate in the DB to the previous SagePay processor?

Comment: Link for SagePay PR info: https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor/pull/42 - if you do use that Omnipay, that's probably where feedback is best directed for now.

Comment: I guess Omnipay extension have cron job that deals with recurring contribution. I am not sure but what i would do is change the civicrm_payment_processor.payment_processor_type of existing payment processor to use new SagePay payment processor type as it will resolve any problem with recurring contribution or auto membership renewal.